Next.JS Sending Multiple Data strings between pages
I have a multi page form, where I have the user upload a file on the first page. The file's database location is then sent to the next page containing more questions.
Now I want to support multiple file uploads. I was using the router.push method to send the file refs in the first page, and the router.query method to capture the single file ref
Now I am trying to send an array containing the file refs, however I am recieving this error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'gcs_uris')
my gcs_uris object is being seen as undefined, and I am unsure why
page_one.tsx:
async function onSubmit(event : FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
      
      event.preventDefault()
      
      const formData = new FormData()
      files.forEach((file) => {
        formData.append('files', file);
      });
  
      
      try{
        const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/Files', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData // Use JSON data as the body
      })
        const responseData = await response.json();
        const gcs_uris = responseData.gcs_uris;
        // Encode the array of GCS URIs as a string
        const encodedUris = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(gcs_uris));

        console.log(gcs_uris)
        router.push(
          `/checklist?gcs_uris=${encodedUris}`, // Construct the URL with query parameter
          '/checklist', // Optional: If you want to set a different `as` path
          { shallow: true } // Optional: For shallow routing (faster navigation)
        );
      }
      catch(err){
        console.log(err)
      }
      
    }

page_two.tsx:
const router = useRouter()

    const [gcsUris, setGcsUris] = useState<string[]>([]);
      
    useEffect(() => {
      // Get the encoded GCS URIs from the query parameter
      const encodedUris = router.query.gcs_uris;
  
      // Decode the encoded string to get the array of GCS URIs
      if (encodedUris) {
        setGcsUris(JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(encodedUris)));
      }
    }, [router.query]);
    
    console.log(gcsUris)

I have tried console.logging the object I send to the other page.  The items contain the file ref strings, so I am unsure why this is happening. I would appreciate any insight to why this is the case

Show responseData.gcs_uris, encodedUris of the previous page and router.query.gcs_uris let us debug.
